# automatic reboot after update 20.04 LTS by itself!

Tags: boot, kernel

I have a big problem!
since the last update from a linux server on 07-30 my server reboots every night by itself!!

```
root@#########:~# last -x reboot
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Wed Aug  3 23:53   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Wed Aug  3 23:24   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Tue Aug  2 23:50   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Tue Aug  2 23:22   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Tue Aug  2 10:35   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Mon Aug  1 23:51   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Mon Aug  1 23:49   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Mon Aug  1 23:23   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Sun Jul 31 23:48   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Sun Jul 31 23:23   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Sat Jul 30 23:46   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Sat Jul 30 23:22   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-122-generi Sat Jul 30 20:45   still running
```

every time just before midnight!
my log book syslog is full of such entries...

```
Aug  3 23:49:19 h2632317 kernel: [ 1502.960356] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=120.76.140.189 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239 ID=56787 PROTO=TCP SPT=51128 DPT=7222 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Aug  3 23:49:38 h2632317 kernel: [ 1522.308959] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=85.215.255.5 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=17834 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=42789 DPT=25 WINDOW=24000 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Aug  3 23:49:52 h2632317 kernel: [ 1535.755524] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=223.71.167.165 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=10237 PROTO=UDP SPT=23616 DPT=6000 LEN=44 
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878679] {2}[Hardware Error]: Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source: 1
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878683] {2}[Hardware Error]: It has been corrected by h/w and requires no further action
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878685] {2}[Hardware Error]: event severity: corrected
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878687] {2}[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: corrected
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878689] {2}[Hardware Error]:  fru_text: CorrectedErr
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878692] {2}[Hardware Error]:   section_type: memory error
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878695] {2}[Hardware Error]:   node: 0 device: 3 
Aug  3 23:49:56 h2632317 kernel: [ 1539.878697] {2}[Hardware Error]:   error_type: 2, single-bit ECC
Aug  3 23:50:29 h2632317 kernel: [ 1572.766854] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=194.26.29.152 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=43707 PROTO=TCP SPT=45358 DPT=4404 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Aug  3 23:50:31 h2632317 kernel: [ 1574.812040] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=78.188.226.9 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=13357 PROTO=TCP SPT=40647 DPT=23 WINDOW=34271 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Aug  3 23:50:51 h2632317 kernel: [ 1594.803119] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=31.43.191.143 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=249 ID=659 PROTO=TCP SPT=49618 DPT=8583 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Aug  3 23:51:25 h2632317 kernel: [ 1628.851786] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:7a:7f:f3:62:00:25:84:7b:bc:00:08:00 SRC=45.61.184.118 DST=81.169.182.188 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=52549 DPT=23 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd-modules-load[549]: Inserted module 'msr'
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd-modules-load[549]: Inserted module 'ipmi_devintf'
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Aug  3 23:54:04 h2632317 systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
```

This is the output of `systemctl list-timers`:

```
root@h2632317:~# systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED              UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Thu 2022-08-04 20:02:17 CEST 43min left    Thu 2022-08-04 13:33:26 CEST 5h 45min ago        ua-timer.timer               ua-timer.service
Thu 2022-08-04 20:15:36 CEST 57min left    Wed 2022-08-03 11:59:28 CEST 1 day 7h ago        mdmonitor-oneshot.timer      mdmonitor-oneshot.service
Thu 2022-08-04 20:17:00 CEST 58min left    Thu 2022-08-04 09:34:02 CEST 9h ago              snap.certbot.renew.timer     snap.certbot.renew.service
Fri 2022-08-05 00:00:00 CEST 4h 41min left Thu 2022-08-04 00:00:01 CEST 19h ago             logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Fri 2022-08-05 00:08:36 CEST 4h 50min left Thu 2022-08-04 00:08:36 CEST 19h ago             systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Fri 2022-08-05 04:13:10 CEST 8h left       Thu 2022-08-04 17:36:04 CEST 1h 42min ago        motd-news.timer              motd-news.service
Fri 2022-08-05 04:36:19 CEST 9h left       Thu 2022-08-04 11:34:13 CEST 7h ago              apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Fri 2022-08-05 05:14:08 CEST 9h left       Thu 2022-08-04 10:49:36 CEST 8h ago              fwupd-refresh.timer          fwupd-refresh.service
Fri 2022-08-05 06:58:40 CEST 11h left      Thu 2022-08-04 06:25:54 CEST 12h ago             apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
Fri 2022-08-05 09:39:16 CEST 14h left      Thu 2022-08-04 03:05:21 CEST 16h ago             mdcheck_continue.timer       mdcheck_continue.service
Sun 2022-08-07 03:10:36 CEST 2 days left   Sun 2022-07-31 03:10:59 CEST 4 days ago          e2scrub_all.timer            e2scrub_all.service
Sun 2022-08-07 16:55:20 CEST 2 days left   Sun 2022-07-03 05:26:09 CEST 1 months 2 days ago mdcheck_start.timer          mdcheck_start.service
Mon 2022-08-08 00:00:00 CEST 3 days left   Mon 2022-08-01 00:00:01 CEST 3 days ago          fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
Mon 2022-08-08 00:00:00 CEST 3 days left   Wed 2022-08-03 00:00:01 CEST 1 day 19h ago       man-db.timer                 man-db.service
```

```
**This i found in the apache error log:**

[Wed Aug 03 23:26:37.959302 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10510] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 03 23:26:37.986934 2022] [core:notice] [pid 10510] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Aug 03 23:55:57.568415 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10495] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 03 23:55:57.596962 2022] [core:notice] [pid 10495] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Aug 04 00:00:11.143900 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10495] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

Comment: do you have a cron job or systemd service set to reboot right before midnight? output from `crontab -l`, `sudo crontab -l`, `systemctl list-timers`, etc

Comment: No any cronjob...

Comment: Not sure check your memory with memtest.

Comment: That's a good idea with the memory . I suspect something... a few days ago I set the memory_limit to 1024M in php.ini...

I will report

Comment: that was it! It was due to the memory_limit in the two php.ini files. I set the cli to memory_limit = -1 and then it worked again 
Thanks nobody!